# Trying to sum an array inside object with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have a problem and I can't find an answer for that issue, I want to add/sum all values from `points` in `points_sum`.

I tried to do this by adding a `for` loop in the object, but then I get:

> 'Unexpected token'

How can I do this in the another way?

```
let sum = 0;
let teams = [
  team1 = {
    name: "Real",
    goal_plus: [3, 4, 2, 1],
    goal_minus: [1, 0, 2, 1],
    points: [3, 3, 3, 1],
    points_sum: for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      sum += points[i];
    }
  },
  team2 = {
    name: "Barca",
    goal_plus: [5, 2, 5, 1],
    goal_minus: [1, 0, 0, 1],
    points: [3, 3, 3, 1],
    points_sum: 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a `for` loop directly inside an object as a value and also you cannot refer to the object keys or values before it has been created, so even if you could add the `for`, that part: 
`i < points.length` would thrown an error, something like *"points is undefined"*, since the object is not created yet and points also doesn't exists in memory.

Another thing, arrays keys can't be named, so keys `team1` and `team2` will be removed from array, only their value will remain (the objects), if you want to keep those names, make the variable `teams` an object, not an array.

A solution to your problem can be: create a function that receives an array and makes the sum for you, I'm using inside this function, the [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
let teams = [
  {
    name: "Real",
    goal_plus: [3, 4, 2, 1],
    goal_minus: [1, 0, 2, 1],
    points: [3, 3, 3, 1],
    points_sum: SumPoints([3, 3, 3, 1]),
  },
  {
    name: "Barca",
    goal_plus: [5, 2, 5, 1],
    goal_minus: [1, 0, 0, 1],
    points: [3, 3, 3, 1],
    points_sum: SumPoints([3, 3, 3, 1])
  }
]

function SumPoints(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}

console.log(teams)
```

Another possible way to solve this, if you can't or don't want to pass the whole array as parameter to a external function, is letting `points_sum` empty and then after creating the array `teams`, do some job to calculate, using a loop method such as `forEach`, see in the below snippet:

```js
let teams = [{
    name: "Real",
    goal_plus: [3, 4, 2, 1],
    goal_minus: [1, 0, 2, 1],
    points: [3, 3, 3, 1],
    points_sum: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Barca",
    goal_plus: [5, 2, 5, 1],
    goal_minus: [1, 0, 0, 1],
    points: [3, 3, 3, 1],
    points_sum: 0
  }
]

teams.forEach(x => {
  x.points_sum = x.points.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
})

console.log(teams)
```

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you for help!